# Particle Filter and Gaussian Mixture

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, particle-filter, weighted-data

Let an observation model be given as $f(y_t|x_t)$ - this pdf is assumed to be nontrivial (not normal, not linear). The observation model is assumed to be known.

Despite there is a state evolution model $f(x_t|x_{t-1})$, this evolution is assumed to be slow and the model completely unknown.

I face the filtration problem, i.e. to get $f(x_t|y_{1:t})$ where $y_{1:t}=(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_{t})$.

My idea is to combine particle filter with weighted Gaussian mixtures and can be summarized in the following steps:

1. Initialization of the particles $x_1^1,x_1^2\dots x_1^P$, set time $t=1$.
2. Calculation of likelihood of particles after new observation $y_t$ obtained, i.e. $w_t^i=f(y_t|x_t^i)$ for all $i=1,\dots,P$.
3. Construction of weighted Gaussian mixture for $f(x_t|y_{1:t})$ that corresponds due to neglecting the dynamics to $f(x_{t+1}|y_{1:t})$. The observations $y_{1:t-1}$ are represented by the particles, the observation $y_t$ by the weights. Thus, the Gaussian mixture I use is a pdf on $x_{t+1}$ and all the observations are implicit only, i.e. I write $f(x_{t+1})$ instead of $f(x_{t+1}|y_{1:t})$. For construction of $f(x_{t+1})$, I use the maximization of the following likelihood function $\prod_{i=1}^P f(x_{t+1}=x_t^i)^{w_t^i}$ that corresponds in logarithm to $\sum_{i=1}^P {w_t^i} \log\left[f(x_{t+1}=x_{t}^i)\right]$.
4. Sampling particles $x_{t+1}^{1},\dots,x_{t+1}^{P}$ from $f(x_{t+1})$, increase $t\gets t+1$, and continue in 2.

My experience with this implementation indicates that the algorithm forgets too fast the past observations. Do you have any idea how to avoid it?

Comment: Just glanced at this, but a few things worth mentioning: 1.) watch out: step 2 is only correct in special cases...actually cases that are impossible if $f(x_t|x_{t-1})$ is 'completely unknown' 2.) Also, you are incorrect in step 3 where you talk about what the particles represent. Finally, what do you mean by 'forgets too fast?'